# Awk print all lines where length is exactly 11 and it starts with zero?

Tags: command-line, printing, sed, awk

I'm parsing some data and I'm looking for a command that allows me to print the lines when the character length is exactly 11 and it starts with zero.

Sounds like it'd be a sed or an awk command, but I can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Using sed:

```
sed -n '/^0.\{10\}$/p' input
```

And using grep:

```
grep '^0.\{10\}$' input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/^0..........$/' infile >outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

grep/ack would be the right tool for this job.

I post another awk oneliner :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=""} NF==11&&$1=="0"' file
```

should give you those lines